# How to trigger an action if there's only one key being pressed?

Tags: scripting, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, key-bindings

Here's my current script:

```
Shift::Send ^{Space}
```

It doesn't only trigger <kbd>^{Space}</kbd> on pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> alone, it also triggers on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (*just these two keys*) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (*just these two keys*) **if <kbd>Shift</kbd> is the last released**, is there a way to trigger <kbd>^{Space}</kbd> if <kbd>Shift</kbd> is the **only** key being pressed?

AutoHotkey Version: 1.1.33.09.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my working script:

```
~*Alt::
~*Ctrl::
~*Shift::return

Shift::SendEvent ^{Space}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have your answer and to think I only learned this today.

```
  ~Shift::return
    #If, A_PriorHotkey = "~Shift"
    Shift Up::
    SendEvent, ^{space}
    #If
    return
```

Worked for me. The ' ~ ' symbol will let you still type capitals although it will still send the ^{space} still. Either delete it (it still works) and/or You will have to make this script Context-sensitive right?

P.s.
I learned it from another code and just adapted it to my and your needs. I needed almost the same thing as you today :-)

Here is the old code I found which I adapted

```
^k::return

#If, A_PriorHotkey = "^k"
^a::ToolTip, % A_ThisHotkey " pressed with ^k"
^b::ToolTip, % A_ThisHotkey " pressed with ^k"
^c::ToolTip, % A_ThisHotkey " pressed with ^k"
^d::ToolTip, % A_ThisHotkey " pressed with ^k"

^k up::SendInput, ^k
#If
```

Comment: I hate to tell you that it's not working for me, it's better than your previous answer (which is good for you), but worse than the current script (`Shift::Send ^{Space}`), since the current script won't trigger the action if shortcuts like Shift+Alt+F being pressed.

Comment: Ok your confusing me. What do you want to do? At 1s you said it still triggers when other modifiers are pressed which you don’t want, then you say you do want that?  My script completely works. Can you kindly please explain more clearly if you have the time exactly want you want?  I tested my script 100 times & it works to what I think you have explained

Comment: _"then you say you do want that"_ I never said I want to trigger the action when other modifiers are pressed. _"since the current script (`Shift::Send ^{Space}`) won't trigger the action if shortcuts like Shift+Alt+F are being pressed"_ Which part is confusing you?

Comment: _"is there a way to trigger `^{Space}` if Shift is the **only** key being pressed?"_ I think I've explained quite clearly in the question description.

Comment: Ok well, my script does exactly what you asked. Can you tell me what my script doesn't do please. you have to be more concise. then people can help you.

Comment: `~Shift::return #If, A_PriorHotkey = "~Shift" Shift Up:: SendEvent, foo #If return` I modified `^{space}` to `foo`, if you press Alt+Shift+C, will it print "foo"?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
~Shift::return
#If, A_PriorHotkey = "~Shift"
Shift Up::SendEvent, foo
!*c::SendEvent, foo
#If
return
```

Comment: With this script, Alt+Shift+C prints "foo" for me, which is unexpected, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Shift::
SendEvent, foo
return
Ctrl & Shift::return
Alt & Shift::return
```

This doesn't work with Numpad keys though for some reason. And again, this script will have to be Context-sensitive.

Comment: Good for you, but it has too many side effects, such as Ctrl+Shift+C (not Shift+Ctrl+C, the order is important here) won't fire the bound action.

Comment: I got a working script from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1670687/1023031), you may find it helpful as well.

Answer (score -1):

Yup Simple, Put the '~ Tilda' key next to it.

```
~Shift::
SendEvent, ^{Space}
return
```

Comment: It's making it worse, now pressing Shift will trigger the action immediately, previously, Shift will trigger only on releasing.